# How to prove $ \int \sqrt{a^2-u^2}du $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I prove that the following definite integral?

$$ \int \sqrt{a^2-u^2}du = \frac{1}{2}\left[u\sqrt{a^2 - u^2} + a^2 \arcsin\left(\frac{u}{a}\right)\right] +C$$

Comment: Integrate by Parts with $\sqrt{a^2-u^2}$ as the first term and $1$ as the second

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use trigonometric substitution. Start with $u=a \sin \theta$. Then $u^2=a^2 \sin^2 \theta$ and $du = a \cos \theta \, d\theta$, so we obtain
\begin{align}\int \sqrt{a^2-u^2} \, du&=\int \sqrt{a^2-a^2 \cos^2 \theta} \cdot a \cos \theta \, d\theta \\
&= \int |a \sin \theta| \cdot a \cos \theta \, d\theta \\
&= a^2 \int \sin \theta \cos \theta \, d\theta
\end{align}
Try to evaluate $\displaystyle a^2\int \sin \theta \cos \theta \, d \theta$, then perform back-substitution so that the final expression of your antiderivative is in terms of the variable $u$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \sqrt{a^2-u^2}du=\int (u)' \sqrt{a^2-u^2}du$$

Now integrate by part:

$$\int (u)' \sqrt{a^2-u^2}du=u\sqrt{a^2-u^2}-\int u (\sqrt{a^2-u^2})'du= \\= u\sqrt{a^2-u^2}+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2u^2}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}}du=u\sqrt{a^2-u^2}+\int \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}}-\sqrt{a^2-u^2}du \\=u\sqrt{a^2-u^2}+\int \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}}-\int \sqrt{a^2-u^2}du$$

So:

$$\int \sqrt{a^2-u^2}du=\frac{1}{2}(u\sqrt{a^2-u^2}+\int \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}}du)$$

But by substitution $t=au$ in second integral you get final result.