# How do I evaluate this integral: $\int_{-3}^{3}[\sqrt{25-x^2}\ - (x^2 - 5)]dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int_{-3}^{3}\sqrt{25-x^2}\,dx - 18$

Then I get this integral $\int_{-3}^{3}\sqrt{25-x^2}\,dx = \int_{-3}^{3}\frac{2x}{2\sqrt {25-x^2}}dx = \int_{-3}^{3}\frac{x}{\sqrt {25-x^2}}dx
$

I know that $\int_{-3}^{3}\frac{dx}{\sqrt {25-x^2}} = ln(5+ {\sqrt {25-x^2}} ) + C
$ but I don't know what to do with the 'x'

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$

Comment: You might find it helpful to [recall that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871159/how-to-prove-int-sqrta2-u2du) $$\int \sqrt{a^2 -x^2}\, dx =  \frac{1}{2}\left[x\sqrt{a^2 - x^2} + a^2 \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right] +C,$$ where $a>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Second, you're confusing definite and indefinite integrals.  Indefinite integrals look like this:

$$\int f(x) \; dx = F(x) +C.$$

Definite integrals look like this"

$$\int_a^b f(x) \; dx = F(b) - F(a).$$

First, your integration by parts in not complete.  You left out the "uv" part (and lost the "v" inside the second integral):

$$\int_{-3}^3 \sqrt{25-x^2} \; dx =  \left.x\sqrt{25-x^2} \right|_{-3}^3 - \int_{-3}^{3} \frac{-x^2}{\sqrt{25-x^2}} \; dx.$$

I don't think parts is the way to do this.  Your new integral is just as ugly as the first.  But if you get an antiderivative, then (and this is your question) you plug in $3$ and $-3$ and subtract.

Probably most people would use the substitution $x=5\sin \theta$ instead of parts.

Answer (score 0):

Use the so-called Euler substitution:
$$\sqrt{25-x^2}=xt+5$$